# Объект поверх другого Java Android

Tags: java, android, android-customview

Для начала обозначу мою цель: Я хочу расположить CustomView типо диалогового окна перед приложением, чтобы я мог одновременно пользоваться им и функциями за ним. Для наглядности я прикрепил скриншот.[image: дополнение]

Comment: FrameLayout в помощь

Comment: а можно подробнее?

Comment: Я думаю, [здесь](https://yandex.ru/search/?text=framelayout%20java%20android&lr=5) достаточно информации :)